# How to find the singularities of the function $z(1-e^{\frac{1}{z}})$ and classify them

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the singularities of the function $z(1-e^{\frac{1}{z}})$ and classify them.

I'm fairly sure that due to the exponential term overpowering the factor $z$, there will be an essential singularity at $z=0$. But I am having some trouble understanding how you may proceed to find other singularities and classify them. 
Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the types of singularities?

Comment: Yes. Removable, pole, or essential. I understand the essential but I am having trouble understanding when to spot the other types

Comment: It is easy to check Laurent series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only point where the function is not defined is $z=0$; it is analytic everywhere else, because its derivative is
$$
f'(z)=1-e^{1/z}+\frac{e^{1/z}}{z}
$$
The singularity at $0$ is essential, because there is no $n\ge0$ such that
$$
\lim_{z\to0}z^nf(z)
$$
is finite: just restrict it to the real axis and try
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{n+1}(1-e^{1/x})=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1-e^t}{t^{n+1}}=-\infty
$$
Thus $z=0$ is neither a removable singularity nor a pole.

There is also a singularity at $\infty$, but for this it's better to study the singularity at $0$ of $g(z)=f(1/z)$:
$$
\lim_{z\to0}g(z)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1-e^z}{z}=-1
$$
so the singularity of $f$ at infinity is removable.